# Is there a website level setting in IIS that would prevent an ASP page from being served?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-6

Trying to copy a website to a new server as the old one is dying.  :(

I tried copying over the files and setting it up manually, but some specific user accounts needed to be used and the guy who set all this up left the company nearly 5 years ago.  And is even worse at documentation than I am.

Anyway, at that point the ASP pages were serving, but getting errors.  Ok, fine... I went back and exported the configuration from the old server (lucky that worked at all) and created a new website from that config on the new server.  On the new website, from the config file, the ASP pages are giving 404 errors.

The Active Server Pages extension is enabled, and I can actually get the asp pages to serve from another website on the server... so I'm thinking it's something at the website level.  No idea what though.

Any ideas?

Comment: The iis install is just corrupt.  The backup and restore of IIS metadata was meant to be server specific and not meant to backup and resore on another machine.  Hopefully you have your restore point of the original IIS metadata.  You could restore to that point and try configuring manually.  Otherwise you will be reinstalling IIS Manually.

Comment: I didn't restore any metadata, just a website configuration...

Comment: Are you sure you are going to the right server and website?  404 is file not found which would suggest either the wrong DNS or path generally.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I was doing classic ASP development we used Parent Paths.  This is at the top of your ASP file you'll see something like;

```
<!--#include file="../../resource/includes/MSSQLconnection.asp"-->
```

This isn't enabled by default in IIS.  It may not be answer but worth looking at.  But was a long time ago now.

Hope this helps,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

404 is a file not found error.

Start by checking you can access a 'hello world' HTML file in the folder using http: //localhost/path/toyour/HelloWorldFile.htm
Hello World 
is all you need in the file = you don't need to bother with any HTML markup to test what we're interested in.

This will check that your virtual directories, application settings etc are correct before you move on to the Active Server Page settings.

Once you've got your paths sorted out and you know you are looking for your application in the correct place move on to a 'hello world' ASP file 
<%="Hello World"%>
is all you need in that file!

You ask about settings in IIS which will stop ASP from working.  These come to mind as the most obvious.

Depending on the OS (or more specifically the IIS version) you may also need to activate ASP pages.
[These instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544765%28v=cs.70%29.aspx) from msdn cover Windows 2003 (IIS6) and Windows 2008(IIS 7.x)
If you can get your hello world script working you can move on to debugging your application.

It will be a great help when debugging the application if you can see what's going wrong so I recommend that you [turn off friendly error messages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778248%28WS.10%29.aspx) if you are using Internet Explorer.  Also set IIS to pass error messages on to the browser

see:
http: //learn.iis.net/page.aspx/564/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default/  --excuse the link formatting but SO's newbies can't post more than 2 hyperlinks in a message was getting in the way of me trying to be helpful and earning enough rep to post more!

(that may only be relevant to IIS 7.x I don't have an IIS6 installation lying around to refresh my memory.

Make sure you are browsing your application on the server using http: //localhost - this should ensure you see any errors

Good luck